# Bison complained "conflicts: 1 shift/reduce"

Tags: bison, yacc

Bison complained "conflicts: 1 shift/reduce". I can't see what's wrong. Please help. Thanks,

```
%token OR AND NUMBER
%%

search_condition:
        |       search_condition AND search_condition { printf(" AND "); }
        |       '(' search_condition ')'
        |       predicate
        ;

predicate:
                NUMBER { printf("%d\n", $1);  }
        ;
```

Comment: I've no experience with Bison/Yacc, but your `search_condition` matches the empty string (epsilon): `search_condition : /* epsilon */ | search_condition AND ...`, perhaps remove the first pipe? `search_condition : search_condition AND ...`?

Comment: Adding %left AND resolved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A conflict means that the grammar you gave to bison is not LALR(1), so it can't decide what action to take in every possible case in order to correctly parse the grammar.

In your case, the problem is that your grammar is ambiguous.  If you give it an input like

```
NUMBER AND NUMBER AND NUMBER
```

it can't decide if it should parse it as equivalent to

```
( NUMBER AND NUMBER ) AND NUMBER
```

or

```
NUMBER AND ( NUMBER AND NUMBER )
```

There are a number of ways you can resolve this:

- you can use `%left AND` or `%right AND` to tell bison that it should treat `AND` as a left- or right-associative infix operator
- you can refactor the `search_condition` rule to make it unambiguous:

  ```
  search_condition : search_condition AND primary
                   | primary
                   ;
  primary : '( search_condition ')'
          | predicate
          ;
  ```